# Random number generation code not working [Probably a stack overflow]

Tags: c, random, overflow, generator, time.h

This C code should generate 1 million random numbers.  I used srand() t aid the pseudrandom generation problem when compiling the code for multiple times. I think theoretically this code should work but it seems that it misses something that might be causing an overflow. any idea why does it stop working during the execution process?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *ofp;
    int k=0, i=1000000;;
    int array[i];

    ofp=fopen("output.txt","w");
    while (ofp==NULL)
    {
        printf("File is corrupted or does not exist, \nplease create or fix the file and press enter to proceed");
        getchar();
    }

    srand(time(NULL));
    rand();

    for (k=0;  k<1000000; k++)
    {
        array[k] = rand()%100;
        fprintf(ofp, "%d\n", array[k]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: The array of 1,000,000 int takes 4MB on a 32-bit machine, so yes, you're probably overflowing the stack. Declare the array as `static`, make it a global, or use `malloc` to create it.

Comment: Using Code Blocks as the IDE , the program stops working (this is the error message).

Answer (score 0):

Fix your code as the following:

```
// ...
#define MAX 1000000
// ...

int main() {

int array[MAX];   // proper static allocation

// ...

if (ofp == NULL) { // while loop has no meaning in here

 // ...  }

 // ... 

 return 0;

 }
```

And do not forget to **close** your opened streams after you're done with them to release allocated resources back to system (in your case your process will eventually be terminated anyway, so it's ok if you did not bother to close it)

Edit: According to C99 spec, it allows some types to be used to initialize statically allocated arrays, however C89 does not. Furthermore, to avoid possible stack overflow issues, try to allocate your array dynamically in your code by calling **malloc** or **calloc** functions. For example:

```
 // ...
 #include <stdlib.h>
 // ...
 int main()
 {
 // ...
 int* array = malloc(sizeof(int) * i);

 // ...
 free(array); // don't forget to free it after you're done.

  return 0;
  }
```